# What options are there for replacing CDONTS in an ASP application on Windows 2003 server

Tags: email, asp-classic

I have a classic ASP application using CDONTS.

What options are available to allow the ASP application to continue sending emails with something that is standard on Windows 2003 server with the .Net framework 2.0 installed.

Comment: I am going to continue to use the ASP application and am looking for something that is built in Windows so as not have to install anything else. There is also no SMTP service installed on the Windows server.

Comment: Then CDOSys is the way to go.  It's automatically on 2K3 servers and works nicely in ASP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to continue to use ASP then you can simply use CDOSYS instead.

Here's a sample on w3schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_send_email.asp

If you want to use the .net framework 2.0 then look into the System.Net.Mail namespace.

If you want to have ASP call the .net framework you can create a console based executable that takes arguments for sender email, receiver email, subject, body and then the console exe will send off the email for your asp app.